# Can I run bash in interactive mode from Java without it suspending the main process?

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, cfml

I'm building a CFML app that uses Java to allow users to run shell commands on Linux.  The entered commands are passed to `bash` with the `-c` option.  To make bash expand aliases I am using the `-i` option to run in interactive mode.  The following lines can be tested from the CommandBox REPL to duplicate the behavior:

```
CWD = createObject( 'java', 'java.io.File' ).init( '/my/working/dir' )
process = createObject( 'java', 'java.lang.Runtime' ).getRuntime().exec( ['bash','-i','-c','ll'], javaCast( 'null', '' ), CWD )
```

This executes and the output of the `ll` command can be accessed via `process.getInputStream()`, however it also suspends the main java process that my CFML engine is running in and drops me at my shell.

```
[1]+  Stopped                 myBinary
[root@host]#
```

Then I have to run `fg` to start back up.  I know it's related to running `bash`  in interactive mode, but how do I avoid this behavior?

I also tried to expand aliases by using the option `-O expand_aliases` or running `shopt -s expand_aliases` but neither of those have any affect.

Comment: You could try [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but the  Lucee CF engine has some nice utilities build around runtime.exec that handle concurrently capturing the error and output streams, etc that's really nice.  I'd like to get this working as it is but keep thinking I'm just missing some simple option somewhere.

Comment: I found a hack adding " && exit" to the end.  I'll give this a few more days and if no one can answer, I'll post that as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did really figure out the "why" of this, but I found a couple of work arounds that at least let me run user-entered bash commands via `Runtime.exec()` that used alias expansion, so I'll share them here for others.  If anyone has a better answer, please add it.

The cleanest way I found was to disable job control (monitor mode) by setting the `+m` option with `set +m;` prior to running the command:

```
process = createObject( 'java', 'java.lang.Runtime' ).getRuntime().exec( [ 'bash','-i','-c', 'set +m; ll' ], javaCast( 'null', '' ), CWD );
```

The only drawback was that worked with `bash`, but didn't work with `zsh` which several of my users like to use on their Mac.

What I ended up doing was adding `&& exit` to the command to exit the shell like so:

```
process = createObject( 'java', 'java.lang.Runtime' ).getRuntime().exec( [ 'bash','-i','-c', 'll && exit'], javaCast( 'null', '' ), CWD );
```

This ran without putting the entire Java process into background mode, but I found two side affects so far:

1. The word "exit" is appended to the standard error.
2. Some commands like `git pull` output the text `bash: no job control in this shell` in the standard error.

Comment: very curious what the answer to "why" is. obviously you can't / don't want to use SSH... but why?

Comment: Well, I'm running the process on the same machine that the CFML (Java) application is running. I'm not sure why I'd want to use SSH for that.

Comment: I am not doubting that you need to use CFML.  I was just wondering what your scenario is that you need to allow users to run commands via cfml when the common thing to do would be to just give users SSH access. 

I fully understand that you are wanting to this with cfml I was just curious what use case its for, as it maybe useful thing to know for the future.

Comment: Sure.  Here is the use-case. CommandBox: (a CFML CLI, REPL, and package manager) that allows the users to run OS commands from the interactive shell (similar to Gant)  http://commandbox.ortusbooks.com/content/v/development/usage/execution/os_binaries.html  Also, if you're curious, the code for this implementation is here: https://github.com/Ortus-Solutions/commandbox/blob/development/src/cfml/system/modules/system-commands/commands/run.cfc#L74